# Why does Canvas overwrite all other things in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-studio

So I've tried to draw a line in Android Studio, using Canvas. In order to draw a simple line, you need to define the contentView using

```
setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
```

I can't seem to make a combination between ImageViews or TextViews, they just overwrite one another.

In order to get the drawn lines, I need to change the contentView to

```
setContentView(DrawView);
```

If I do this, all my other things disappear.

Here are my 2 files:

**MainActivity:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawView drawLine;
    ImageView view;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    DrawView drawView;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
        view.setZ(-1);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChanged = 0;
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressChanged = progress;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                text.setText("Progress: " + progressChanged);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**DrawView:**

```
public class DrawView extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
}
```

}

How can I combine both the TextViews and/or ImageViews with the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to draw a simple line, you need to define the contentView using

Not necessarily.

> In order to get the drawn lines, I need to change the contentView to

Not necessarily.

> How can I combine both the TextViews and/or ImageViews with the canvas?

Step #1: Implement the two-argument constructor on `DrawView`, that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`.

Step #2: In your layout resource file that has your `ImageViews` and `TextViews`, *also* have your `DrawView`. Note that you will need to use the fully qualified class name in the XML element name (e.g., `com.eriklann.android.DrawView`).